# Play a sound on every new visit to everyone who is connected

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I have this simple php where it writes every visit on a text.
What i m looking for is a way to play a sound to everyone who is connected on the site, when a new visitor arrives. Any ideas?

```
<div id="test" align="center"> 
<?php $handle = fopen("counter.txt", "r"); 
if(!$handle){ echo "could not open the file" ; }
else { $counter = ( int ) 
fread ($handle,20) ; fclose ($handle) ; 
$counter++ ; echo" <strong> you are visitor no ".
$counter . "  " ; $handle = fopen("counter.txt", "w" ) ;
fwrite($handle,$counter) ; fclose ($handle) ; } 
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Please only use the relevant tags. as the one answer implies: no idea what you are asking for. Beyond that: why would somebody visiting your site want to be notified about other people visiting it?

Comment: I m sorry for the tags. Only 2 users are connected to the site and i need to get notified when the other user is connected so i can leave the work that has to be done to him. And when i connect he will get notified and leave the work up to me

Comment: you'll need something like https://pusher.com/ or https://socket.io/, along with the answer provided.

Comment: Pushing notifications is what i needed. I used notifymydevice and iframe

Comment: yeah, thats what pusher and socket.io are for too!

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with php really, since you cant play an audio with php, at least not on the users browser...

What you are looking for is this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement

And you can use it like this:

```js
var welcomeAudioclip = new Audio('the_great_southern_trendkill.mp3');
welcomeAudioclip.play();
```

Comment: I don;t know how exactly to use the code. I tried to put it inside a <script> but it does not play any sound..

Comment: Oh a wav file you mean. yes  i did

Comment: are you on IExplorer? if you can convert to mp3, or use other browser it should work... i think there's some problems with .wav support